# Exclude entry types from calculation of \shorthandwidth

Tags: biblatex

`biblatex` automatically calculates `\shorthandwidth` based on the maximum length of all `shorthand` fields included in the list of shorthands.

How can I exclude all entry types except one from this calculation?

**Note:** I do not want to use the `skipbiblist` option as this completely removes the entry from the list of shorthands, which I do not want to happen.

(The end goal is to correctly calculate the width of all abbreviations in a combined list of abbreviations. Many entry types have a `shorttitle` field, but I only want this field included in the list of abbreviations for *one* entry type. Hence I only want these entry types to contribute towards the calculation of `\shorttitlewidth`, which in turn will be used to calculate the maximum abbreviation width. The reason the `skipbiblist` option can't be used is because other entry types with a `shorttitle` may still need to appear in the list of abbreviations under a different label field. This question is simplified to only worry about `shorthand`. Other suggested solutions to the general problem that don't specifically answer this question are welcome.)

## MWE

In the following MWE, I'd like to exclude all entry types except `@book` from the calculation of `\shorthandwidth` without (necessarily) excluding other entries from the list of shorthands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  shorthand = {Foo},
  author = {Author},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2020}
}
@misc{test2,
  shorthand = {FooBar},
  author = {Author},
  title = {Foo Bar Title},
  date = {2020}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\verb+\the\shorthandwidth+: \the\shorthandwidth

goal for \verb+\the\shorthandwidth+: 21.52785pt (exclude \texttt{@book} entry
type).

\printbiblist{shorthand}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not going to print the `shorthand` in the list of shorthands for those entries where it shouldn't be measured, it would work to set the `shorthandwidth` field format to empty and set the desired format only for `@book` entries.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{shorthandwidth}{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  shorthand = {Foo},
  author    = {Author},
  title     = {Title},
  date      = {2020},
}
@misc{test2,
  shorthand = {FooBar},
  author    = {Author},
  title     = {Foo Bar Title},
  date      = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\verb+\the\shorthandwidth+: \the\shorthandwidth

goal for \verb+\the\shorthandwidth+: 21.52785pt (exclude \texttt{@book} entry
type).

\printbiblist{shorthand}
\end{document}
```

[image: \the\shorthandwidth: 15.97227pt]

If you still want to print the `shorthand` for all entries, you can redefine the `shorthand` bibliography environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{shorthandwidth}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandprint}{#1}

\defbibenvironment{shorthand}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandprint]{shorthand}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  shorthand = {Foo},
  author    = {Author},
  title     = {Title},
  date      = {2020},
}
@misc{test2,
  shorthand = {FooBar},
  author    = {Author},
  title     = {Foo Bar Title},
  date      = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\verb+\the\shorthandwidth+: \the\shorthandwidth

goal for \verb+\the\shorthandwidth+: 21.52785pt (exclude \texttt{@book} entry
type).

\printbiblist{shorthand}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ta, I think the first option is true and this works.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\llap` excludes the entry from the calculation. It gives the strange brackets around the abbreviation, but, as I understand, you can use a style without brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  shorthand = {Foo},
  author = {Author},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2020}
}
@misc{test2,
  shorthand = {\llap{FooBar}},
  author = {Author},
  title = {Foo Bar Title},
  date = {2020}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\verb+\the\shorthandwidth+: \the\shorthandwidth

goal for \verb+\the\shorthandwidth+: 21.52785pt (exclude \texttt{@misc} entry
type).

\printbiblist{shorthand}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hmmm. this *might* work for me. Although I'd do it using a field format rather than hacking with the bib entry itself. Let me do some tests.

Comment: I'd probably prefer a lower level solution though. Especially as I accidentally twisted my logic in the question (edited now). I actually want to exclude all entry types except one.

Comment: @DavidPurton As far as I understand, you want now to use only one entry to set the `\shorthandwidth`. So why not, say, `\setlength\shorthandwidth{25pt}`? (Certainly, the version with a calculated value is a simple modification of the preceding setting).

Comment: No, this is the problem with MWE. The real example is much more complicated. Ultimately, I want a width that is the maximum of shorthand, shortjournal, shortseries, and shortitle for only one entry type. Except that shorttitle can and does appear in a variety of entry types (only one entry type should place shorttitle in the list of abbreviations though).